# In a Banach space, can there be a closed subspace which does not have a closed complement?

Tags: banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a Banach space and $X$ be a closed subspace of $V$. When $X$ is finite dimensional, the existence of its closed complement, that is, some closed subspace $Y$ such that $X\oplus Y=V$, follows from Hahn-Banach theorem.

What if $X$ is infinite dimensional? Is there a counter example?

Comment: Yes, the canonical example is $\ell_1$

Comment: Every closed subspace of $X$ has  a closed complement if and only if $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space. Ref: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02771592

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment might be a little too brief, so I'll extend it a touch.  You can look all of this up in *Kalton and Albiac's* Topics in Banach Space Theory (section 2.3) for the details, but in essence:

If $X$ is a separable Banach space then we can construct a continuous operator $Q: \ell_1 \rightarrow X$.  This is done by restricting ourselves first to the unit ball (since it's easy to extend out to the full Banach space after that's been established) and defining $Q$ in the "obvious" way; i.e.

$$Q(\xi) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \xi_n x_n $$

where $\{x_n\}_{n \in {\mathbb N}}$ is a countable dense subset of $X\cap B_X$ and $B_X$ is the unit ball in $X$, and $\xi = (\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots )$ is an element of $\ell_1$.  We can quickly show that $Q$ is linear and has norm one, and with a little more work (this is bulk of the proof) that $Q(B_{\ell_1})$ is dense in $B_X$.

Now, since $X$ is separable it is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_1$, and we can reach our conclusion: suppose $X$ is *not* isomorphic to $\ell_1$ and consider the closed subspace $\mathop{ker} Q$.  Since $X = \ell_1 / \mathop{ker} Q$ this is isomorphic to a closed subspace of $\ell_1$, which requires $X$ to be isomorphic to $\ell_1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why is $X=\ell_1/ker Q$ isomorphic to a closed subspace of $\ell_1$?

Comment: @uniquesolution If $\mathop{ker}$ Q were to be complemented in $\ell_1$ then $\ell_1$ would have to be $\mathop {ker} Q \oplus M$ for some closed subspace $M \subseteq \ell_1$ and $X$ is then isomorphic to $M$.  (But a Banach space that is a complemented infinite dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ for $1\leq p \lt \infty$ is isomorphic to $\ell_p$)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but your argument seems to run as follows: "Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Then $X$ is isometrically isomorphic to a quotient of $\ell_1$. Therefore $X$ is isomorphic to $\ell_1$." ?

Comment: @uniquesolution the point of the argument is that $\ell_1$ has an uncomplemented closed subspace.  I'm happy for you to vote to delete my answer, of course (and I have upvoted yours).  I'm afraid the OP has accepted this so I can't delete for you -- perhaps you could petition them to give you the tick instead?

Comment: I care not for the votes; I haven't downvoted yours. I simply don't follow your argument, nor your explanation. Probably mea culpa.

Comment: @uniquesolution now I'm lost.  You've summarised the argument correctly: we assume that $X$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_1$ and the $\ell_1$ has an uncomplemented closed subspace and we show that this means that $X$ *is* isomorphic to $\ell_1$, which is a contradiction.  Given you've accurately summarised that I can't see what else I can say to you :(  So all I can suggest is that this answer isn't good enough and should be downvoted and deleted.

Comment: I summarised my confusion. Consider this: 1) $\ell_2$ is not isomorphic to $\ell_1$. 2) $\ell_2$ is isometric to a quotient of $\ell_1$, as is any other separable Banach space. Your argument claims now that $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to $\ell_1$, contradiction. I don't see why I cannot apply your argument to get this absurdity.

Comment: @uniquesolution You're claiming that $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a *closed* subspace of $\ell_1$ in order to reach your absurdity (which is genuinely absurd, true) but I can't see how you're getting that closure.  That $\ell_1$ has such a closed subspace is a hypothesis in my argument in order to derive the contradiction -- and that then precludes complementation.  If you want to use the same contradiction you're going to have to show that $\ell_2$ is isomorphic to a closed subspace of $\ell_1$ and I don't think you can

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed out by Kavi Rama Murthy, there is a theorem, already $50$ years old by now, proved by Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri, asserting that a Banach space $X$ is isomorphic to Hilbert space if and only if every closed subspace of $X$ is complemented. Therefore, every infinite dimensional Banach space not isomorphic to Hilbert space, contains uncomplemented subspaces.
For a survey on the topic, see here: [A survey on the complemented subspace problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0501048.pdf).